# Can I tell rollup to not minimize the code it generates?

Tags: javascript, bundler, minify, rollupjs

I understand that I can generate a source map, but I want to generate the rollup output without minification.  Is it possible to do this? I've googled and haven't found anybody asking this question.

Comment: doesn't rollup only minify if you use an external minification plugin like terser?

Comment: @selfagency the documentation suggests otherwise: there is an option on whether or not to output a source map

Answer (score 3):

usually with rollup:

javascript is minified by [@rollup/plugin-terser](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/terser)
to disable minifacation of javascript
remove `terser()` from the `plugins` array in `rollup.config.js`

by default, CSS is not minified by [rollup-plugin-css-only](https://github.com/thgh/rollup-plugin-css-only) or [rollup-plugin-postcss](https://github.com/egoist/rollup-plugin-postcss)

`rollup-plugin-css-only` has no option for minify
`css({ output: 'bundle.css' })`

`rollup-plugin-postcss` has the default option `{ minimize: false }`
`postcss({ extract: 'bundle.css' })`

other rollup plugins can produce minified CSS, for example [rollup-plugin-svelte](https://github.com/sveltejs/rollup-plugin-svelte)

as a workaround, to produce pretty CSS, im using the build script
`rollup -c && prettier -w public/build/bundle.css`
with `npm i -D prettier`

all of this may be simpler when migrating from `rollup` to `vite`
see also [How do I disable minification when running "build" command in sveltekit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71767581/how-do-i-disable-minification-when-running-build-command-in-sveltekit)
and [sveltejs: Switch existing project from rollup to vite](https://www.reddit.com/r/sveltejs/comments/sypu7n/switch_existing_project_from_rollup_to_vite_whats/)
and [awesome-vite](https://github.com/vitejs/awesome-vite)

example `vite.config.js`

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import { svelte } from '@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte';

export default defineConfig({
  // use relative paths to asset files
  // https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/762
  base: './',
  plugins: [
    svelte(),
  ],
  build: {
    // dont minify JS and CSS
    minify: false,
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        // remove hashes from output paths
        // https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/378
        entryFileNames: `assets/[name].js`,
        chunkFileNames: `assets/[name].js`,
        assetFileNames: `assets/[name].[ext]`
      }
    }
  },
});
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, this question (or one similar) was asked [here](https://github.com/open-wc/open-wc/issues/543).

It seems that there isn't a way to do it based on that. I don't know what your exact use case for this is, but maybe you can run it through [rollup-plugin-esformatter](https://github.com/mjeanroy/rollup-plugin-esformatter) to make your code readable.

Comment: I did find that answer, but it seemed to be for an unrelated project, so I didn't put too much weight into the replies

Comment: The use case for me is easy debugging. Is there a method others use for this?

Comment: @Loopy [Source maps](https://web.dev/articles/source-maps)?