# How do I disable minification when running "build" command in sveltekit?

Tags: svelte, vite, sveltekit

I am deploying sveltekit to a dfinity container and I need to disable minification to debug.

I have to build a static version to deploy it with `npm run build` -- is there a vite option to disable minification?

I've tried this: `svelte.config.js` but it doesn't do anything:

```js
vite: {
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            $components: path.resolve('./src/components'),
            $stores: path.resolve('./src/stores'),
            $api: path.resolve('./src/api')
        }
    },
    build: {
        minify: false
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue. `vite.build.minify=false` does actually disable minification in a newly scaffolded SvelteKit project. Can you share a link to a reproduction of the problem?

Comment: that works. it still compiled it but did not minify. so we're good.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `vite.config.js/ts` instead, and set the build.minify option:

```
import { sveltekit } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [sveltekit()],
    build: {
        minify: false
    }
});
```

[Reference](https://vitejs.dev/config/build-options.html#build-minify)